# How to get to modwsgi 4+ on Centos7

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, python, mod-wsgi

On Centos7, yum pulls in mod_wsgi 3.4 using a yum install.  I'm having some problems and multiple resources I have looked at regard this version as ancient and ask the users to upgrade to 4+.  I'm not finding the packages online nor any upgrade paths for CentOS like systems.  Has anyone gotten a higher version than mod_wsgi 3.4 installed properly on CentOS7 for an apache/python/wsgi configuration?

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS 7 you can use a Software Collection to get a later version of Python (e.g. 3.6 or 3.8) both of which include mod_wsgi 4.5 and 4.6 respectively.

It's better though if you upgrade to CentOS 8 (you run a web site, why haven't you done this already?!?) where you can use module streams, a much more straightforward approach than the old Software Collections. In either case you can choose Python 3.6 or 3.8, both of which supply mod_wsgi 4.6.

Comment: Thank you!  I will give that a shot, good point on CentOS8